# All they want to do was kiss the ground

Tags: tense-agreement

> All they want to do ***was*** kiss the ground that their lungs can still pump air and rest.

Is *was* the correct verb?

Answer (score 1):

"Want" is present tense, and "was" is past tense. So you should use "is" instead, which is the present tense of the term "was".